# Is it realistic to think that enough Democrats can register as Republicans and nominate a non-Trump Republican in the 2020 primaries?

Tags: united-states, president, presidential-election, primaries

And what is the potential impact (other than many Democrats not having a say in their own candidate) of a legitimate campaign to try to convince Democrats to do so?

Comment: I see this seems based on a certain opinion piece https://www.huffpost.com/entry/why-democrats-could-consider-registering-republican_b_5999c872e4b02eb2fda320f8

Comment: It would require a large amount of overt coordination, which GOP officials could cite as justification to change their nomination rules to thwart the effort.

Comment: @Colin change the nomination system so only people officials approve of are allowed to vote in it? Sounds a great way to lose support generally.

Comment: @Jontia Nah, the GOP does stuff like that all the time.

Comment: @Jontia That's basically what the Democrats did in 2016, with their large number of superdelegates.

Comment: @Jontia In this (extremely hypothetical) scenario, such a change would be widely seen as a justified effort to stop people from gaming the system ("brigading").

Answer (score 7):

No it's not a realistic plan. It would require massive coordination in multiple states, which would be apparent and make their own primary more susceptible to a similar attack. This would be viewed negatively by large portions of the country; sinking a particular opposing candidate is more important than selecting a quality candidate of their own is a bad message to send. The GOP could simply change the rules in the face of such an attempt, depending on how they did this and how apparent Democrat interference was Republicans may not even see any backlash for changing the rules.

Any candidate that could be chosen on the Republican side would still be someone the Democrats don't like, they would be a somewhat popular Republican. Such an action of outright disenfranchising of Republican voters in their own primary would create a lot of sympathy for them and may cascade to a Republican victory in the general election, which would be a defeat for Democrats anyway.